# Could not load assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design when running Add-Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-1.1

I have created a Class Library project with the following .csproj:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When running the command:

```
Add-Migration -Name Test -Context TestContext
```

I am getting the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String environment)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is already installed.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 (VisualStudio/15.0.0+26228.9)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It worked after adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet and changing the versions of dotnet tools to 1.0.0-msbuild2-final, now my .csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: This works, but it's concerning as to why this is a requirement.

Comment: EFCore is not supposed to require .NET Core, but "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" requires .NET Core. Sigh.

Answer (score 5):

for me, it worked fine after setting the start up project to the class library also you can do it without setting the start up project by using the command

```
Add-Migration -project [ProjectName] initDB
```

also here is my .csproj for reference

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />  
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
</ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: Wow.  Who'd have thought setting the startup project to a class library would fix this!  Solved my problem, even though I had the class library selected in packager manager console!

Comment: Worked for me after setting the startup project.

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions from Bart Lannoeye:

UWP apps can’t run in the AnyCPU configuration
I chanbged my project to run in x86 and migrations started to work.

http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/ef-core-migrations-throws-exception-calling-createinstanceandunwrap

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a specific version of Visual Studio (15.4.5) failing to read the IDE settings.  [From this workaround from Ben Day](https://www.benday.com/2017/03/14/a-non-terrible-workaround-for-the-dreaded-ef-core-migration-fileloadexception-diagnostics-problem/) I explicitly set the setup project and Migrations project on the command line.

These two commands were formatted in this manner to make it work.

```
PM> cd [migrations directory]
PM> Add-Migration -Name [version label] -Context [your context] -s [startup project]
```