# entity framework database first occurs messy code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I follow Microsoft's Tutorials about entity framework, database first.
when I run the code :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(local);Database=PADAccountHXHis;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Verbose
```

vs2017 give me the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   δ�ܼ����ļ������Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design��������ĳһ�������ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ�����ļ���
>   �ļ���:��Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design��

yes,there are some messy code.
thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the solution from this thread:

[Could not load assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design when running Add-Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053031/could-not-load-assembly-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-design-when-running-add-mi)

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes,it is helpful.but a new error raise up:
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(local);Database=PADAccountHXHis;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Verbose
Using project 'PADBrushSystem'.
Using startup project 'PADBrushSystem'.
Build started...
Build failed.

Comment: i found it.the solution must be generated. it's OK now.

Comment: glad to be of help

Comment: there is another question should pay attention to.Execute EF's Commands should at the start project,there are several projects in my solution,but at first,i run th ef's command at XXX.Models(one of the projects in the solution).now,i can run ef's command sucess.thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have more problems, feel free to ask questions here.